# Python: nested for loop - name not defined

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, nested, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

first of all, I must point out that i'm not a programmer, so this is probably a stupid question, but i'd like to understand what's going on here.

The program should go through a string (genome), and slide a window of arbitrary length ('l' in this case). It searches for repeating sequences of characters of a given length (k) and notes the number of occurrences of a sequence. I did manage to find repeated sequences in the whole string, but the said window is troubling me. I tried using a nested loop:

```
for i in range(len(genome) - k + 1):
    for c in range(len(genome))[c:c+l]:
        kmer = genome[i:i+k]
        if kmer in d:
            d[kmer] += 1
        else:
            d[kmer] = 1
```

I get an error: "NameError: name 'c' is not defined"
What is the cause of this problem, and is there an easy to comprehend way of fixing it? Efficiency is not really important, so i'd like to keep a similar structure (i found a lot of topics describing ways to avoid using nested for loop, but i find it quite confusing presently).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you intending `for c in range(len(genome))[c:c+l]` to do?  The `for` is supposed to define what you want `c` to iterate over, so you can't use `c` in the `for` expression itself.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what a stupid mistake this is. Basically, i wanted the second loop to "limit" the original string to a certain length, and find the most repetitive sequences of characters within that window - that is the condition of the problem, finding sequences that are most often, but again, only within a segment of the string.

"...Our plan is to slide a window of fixed length L along the genome, looking for a region where a k-mer appears several times in short succession... "

Comment: Can you explain what you want `c` and `k` to represent?  I understand you're sliding a window of length `l`, but I don't understand what you want to do within that window.  Also, I assume `d` is a dict holding counts, but is it supposed to hold the total number of `kmer`s seen, or just the number in the current window?

Comment: Let's say i have a string "ATCGATCGTAGCGCGGGGCACGCGGACTGCTGTGCTAGTA". That is the 'genome' variable. I need to find what sequence of letters appears most often (in a certain window), and the length of it should be 'k'. I used 'c' only to have a counter that can dictate the start and the end of the window in which to compare the sequences.

--edit--

D holds the number of times every different sequence of length 'k' appears in any window. I just use the max value, and if there are more sequences with the same occurrence, i just print them all, i already did that on a simpler problem.

Comment: @user2984872: I've edited my answer to what I think you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `c` in the second `for` loop, and trying to use it in the same statement. Thus, `c` is not defined until you begin the `for` loop, so is not defined.

**Edit**

Judging by your comments, I believe what you are trying to do is slide a window of length `l` along a genome. Then you want to find the window that is enriched for some k-mer(s). To do that, I would modify your second loop to look at the next `l` locations from the current window start:

```
for c in range(i, i+l):
```